# Unable add product to cart after changing from production mode to developer mode

Tags: magento2

After changing magento2 from production mode to developer mode, **I cannot add product to cart**.
When click "add to cart" button, it just shows "Adding" and nothing happen.

Environment :
Window 8
PHP 7
Properly set permission on pub/static and var/generation var/view_preprocessed according http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html
[image]

Comment: enable the magento, and let meb know what happen?

Comment: As I said, it just shows "adding" and nothing happen. The "add to cart" functionality works well on Firefox but on Chrome nothing happen. Not sure why ?

Answer (score 3):

Can you please run below command once:

```
<your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
<your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:upgrade
<your Magento install dir>/bin/magento indexer:reindex
<your Magento install dir>/bin/magento cache:flush
```

that may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. It works on Chrome as well. Not sure why.  maybe because cache ?

Comment: Actually, it happens due to caches. Just flush caches and it will work